# Pgfplots: enlargelimits=false in addplot3 inconsistent behavior

Tags: pgfplots, plot, 3d

I try to plot some 3D stuff. I use `enlargelimits=false` key in the `pgfplotsset` definition and restrict the `domain` to -1:1.

When plotting the first function, everything works fine. The axis reaches exactly from -1 to 1:

[image]

However, when I use the same style for another picture, it seems like the `enlargelimits=false` has no effect:

[image]

Can someone explain why this is and what I can do to prevent this behavior?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{%
  shapefunctionaxis/.style={%
    domain=-1.0:1.0,
    domain y=-1.0:1.0,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis equal,
    xlabel=$\xi$,
    ylabel=$\eta$,
    zlabel=$N_{\i}$,
    zlabel style={rotate=-90},
    xtick distance={1.0},
    ytick distance={1.0},
    ztick distance={1.0},
    view={25}{30},% default is {25}{30}, pgfplots manual section 4.11.1
  }%
}

\begin{document}

% This works as expected:
\def\i{5}
\def\xii{0}
\def\etai{1.0}
% This does not work as expected:
%\def\i{4}
%\def\xii{-1.0}
%\def\etai{1.0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,
    shapefunctionaxis,
  ]
    % Corner nodes
    \ifnum\ifnum\i=1 1\else\ifnum\i=2 1\else\ifnum\i=3 1\else\ifnum\i=4 1\else0\fi\fi\fi\fi%
      =1 %
      \addplot3[surf]{0.25*(1.0+\xii*x)*(1.0+\etai*y)*(\xii*x+\etai*y-1)};
    \else\fi
    % xi-edge middle nodes
    \ifnum\ifnum\i=5 1\else\ifnum\i=7 1\else0\fi\fi%
      =1 %
      \addplot3[surf]{0.5*(1.0-x*x)*(1.0+\etai*y)};
    \else\fi
    % eta-edge middle nodes
    \ifnum\ifnum\i=6 1\else\ifnum\i=8 1\else0\fi\fi%
      =1 %
      \addplot3[surf]{0.5*(1.0+\xii*x)*(1.0-y*y)};
    \else\fi
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual

> `/pgfplots/axis equal={⟨true,false⟩}` (initially `false`)
>   Each unit vector is set to the same length while the axis dimensions stay
>   constant. Afterwards, the size ratios for each unit in x and y will be
>   the same.
>   Axis limits will be enlarged to compensate for the scaling
>   effect.

---

### Edit by krtek

The option `unit rescale keep size=true` was exactly the right hint. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{%
  shapefunctionaxis/.style={%
    domain=-1.0:1.0,
    domain y=-1.0:1.0,
    enlargelimits=false,
    %axis equal,
    unit rescale keep size=true,
    xlabel=$\xi$,
    ylabel=$\eta$,
    zlabel=$N_{\i}$,
    zlabel style={rotate=-90},
    xtick distance={1.0},
    ytick distance={1.0},
    ztick distance={1.0},
    view={25}{30},% default is {25}{30}, pgfplots manual section 4.11.1
  }%
}

\begin{document}

% This works as expected:
%\def\i{5}
%\def\xii{0}
%\def\etai{1.0}
% These does not work as expected:
\def\i{4}
\def\xii{-1.0}
\def\etai{1.0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,
    shapefunctionaxis,
  ]
    % Corner nodes
    \ifnum\ifnum\i=1 1\else\ifnum\i=2 1\else\ifnum\i=3 1\else\ifnum\i=4 1\else0\fi\fi\fi\fi%
      =1 %
      \addplot3[surf]{0.25*(1.0+\xii*x)*(1.0+\etai*y)*(\xii*x+\etai*y-1)};
    \else\fi
    % xi-edge middle nodes
    \ifnum\ifnum\i=5 1\else\ifnum\i=7 1\else0\fi\fi%
      =1 %
      \addplot3[surf]{0.5*(1.0-x*x)*(1.0+\etai*y)};
    \else\fi
    % eta-edge middle nodes
    \ifnum\ifnum\i=6 1\else\ifnum\i=8 1\else0\fi\fi%
      =1 %
      \addplot3[surf]{0.5*(1.0+\xii*x)*(1.0-y*y)};
    \else\fi
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alright, so the problem is that the z-range is larger than 1?! Is there a possibility to only have equal x- and y-axis?

Comment: @krtek Perhaps `unit rescale keep size` is what you need. See the manual page 295-297.